# How come I keep getting this error ERROR Router' is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I keep getting this error in my react app:

ERROR

[eslint]
src\App.js
Line 14:6:   'Router' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
Line 15:8:   'Navbar' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
Line 16:8:   'Routes' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
Line 17:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 18:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 19:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 20:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 21:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 22:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 23:10:  'Route' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This is my NavbarElements.js code:

```
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
  
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #63D471;
  height: 85px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.2rem calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
  z-index: 12;
  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */
`;
  
export const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #808080;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    color: #000000;
  }
`;
  
export const Bars = styled(FaBars)`
  display: none;
  color: #808080;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 75%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
  
export const NavMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: -24px;
  /* Second Nav */
  /* margin-right: 24px; */
  /* Third Nav */
  /* width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap; */
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;
  
export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 24px;
  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100vw; */
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;
  
export const NavBtnLink = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #808080;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  color: #000000;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Second Nav */
  margin-left: 24px;
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #808080;
  }
`;
```

This is the code in my app.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages";
import About from "./pages/about";
import Awards from "./pages/awards";
import Contact from "./pages/contact";
import Education from "./pages/education";
import Projects from "./pages/projects";
import Skills from "./pages/skills";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/education' component={Education} />
        <Route path='/skills' component={Skills} />
        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
        <Route path='/awards' component={Awards} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

and finally my package.json file to show my dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "react-feedback-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why I got these error codes please?

Answer (score 0):

Missing from your project's dependencies is the `react-icons` package. It needs to be added to the project.

Run: `npm i -s react-icons` to add it to the project ***and*** save the package.json file.

The is no imported `Navbar` component.

```
import "./components/Navbar";
```

should be something like

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
```

Just make sure that a `Navbar` component is *actually* exported from that location.

The `Router`, `Routes`, and `Route` components also need to be imported.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Additionally, you are using `react-router-dom@6` and the component APIs changed significantly from previous versions. The `Route` component renders its content on a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/education' element={<Education />} />
        <Route path='/skills' element={<Skills />} />
        <Route path='/projects' element={<Projects />} />
        <Route path='/awards' element={<Awards />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```